# how to put horizontal scroll bar entire page when the user resize the browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

how to put horizontal scroll bar entire page when the user resize the browser

http://jsfiddle.net/czaL4te7/1/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body style="background-color:yellow">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading  text-center" style="background-color:red;color:white;">Sources</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <table class="table-bordered">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="background-color:red;">Label1</td>
                                <td><input type="text" /></td>
                                <td style="background-color:red;">Label2</td>
                                <td><input type="text" /></td>
                                <td style="background-color:red;">Label3</td>
                                <td><input type="text" /></td>
                                <td style="background-color:red;">Label4</td>
                                <td><input type="text" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="panel-body">

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Firstname</th>
                                        <th>Lastname</th>
                                        <th>Email</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>John</td>
                                        <td>Doe</td>
                                        <td>john@example.com</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Mary</td>
                                        <td>Moe</td>
                                        <td>mary@example.com</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>July</td>
                                        <td>Dooley</td>
                                        <td>july@example.com</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Firstname</th>
                                        <th>Lastname</th>
                                        <th>Email</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>John</td>
                                        <td>Doe</td>
                                        <td>john@example.com</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Mary</td>
                                        <td>Moe</td>
                                        <td>mary@example.com</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>July</td>
                                        <td>Dooley</td>
                                        <td>july@example.com</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Firstname</th>
                                        <th>Lastname</th>
                                        <th>Email</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>John</td>
                                        <td>Doe</td>
                                        <td>john@example.com</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Mary</td>
                                        <td>Moe</td>
                                        <td>mary@example.com</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>July</td>
                                        <td>Dooley</td>
                                        <td>july@example.com</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="panel-heading  text-center" style="background-color:red;color:white;">Rules</div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <table class="table table-striped">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center;background-color:red;">Common header</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th style="text-align:left;background-color:red; border: 1px solid white;">Firstname</th>
                                                <th style="text-align:left;background-color:red;">Lastname</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>John</td>
                                                <td>Doe</td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Mary</td>
                                                <td>Moe</td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>July</td>
                                                <td>Dooley</td>

                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <table class="table table-striped">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                                <th>Lastname</th>

                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>John</td>
                                                <td>Doe</td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Mary</td>
                                                <td>Moe</td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>July</td>
                                                <td>Dooley</td>

                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <table class="table table-striped">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                                <th>Lastname</th>

                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>John</td>
                                                <td>Doe</td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Mary</td>
                                                <td>Moe</td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>July</td>
                                                <td>Dooley</td>

                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="panel-heading  text-center" style="background-color:red;color:white;">Rules</div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <table class="table table-striped">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                                <th>Lastname</th>

                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>John</td>
                                                <td>Doe</td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Mary</td>
                                                <td>Moe</td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>July</td>
                                                <td>Dooley</td>

                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="panel-heading  text-center" style="background-color:red;color:white;">Rules</div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <table class="table table-striped">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                                <th>Lastname</th>

                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>John</td>
                                                <td>Doe</td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Mary</td>
                                                <td>Moe</td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>July</td>
                                                <td>Dooley</td>

                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code puts the controls vertically when the user resize it. 
But I don't want that. 
I want the horizontal scroll to come  and keep the layout as such.

Also the page should work in all the screen resolutions

Please help

Comment: you need to use some `min-width` `max-width` @media queries.

Comment: And where that should be placed in the body?